# Optimising query with composite index, which says using where

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, indexing, range

I have the following table "endgames" as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DB`.`endgames`; 
    CREATE TABLE `DB`.`endgames` ( 
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `GamePosition` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0123421055555555CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCBBBBBBBB6789A876', 
    `GameIntroduction` text, 
    `Event` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `Site` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `GameDate` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `Round` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `WhitePlayer` varchar(80) NOT NULL, 
    `BlackPlayer` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `Result` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    `ECOCode` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    `Annotator` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `EventCountry` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `GameText` text, 
    `WhiteMove` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1', 
    `MoveOffset` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0', 
    `TextComments` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    `VariationCount` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    `WhiteQueenCount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `WhiteRookCount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `WhiteBishopCount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `WhiteKnightCount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `WhitePawnCount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `BlackQueenCount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `BlackRookCount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `BlackBishopCount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `BlackKnightCount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `BlackPawnCount` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), 
    KEY `IX_PieceCounts`  (`WhiteQueenCount`,`WhiteRookCount`,`WhiteBishopCount`,`WhiteKnightCount`,`WhitePawnCount`,`BlackQueenCount`,`BlackRook
    Count`,`BlackBishopCount`,`BlackKnightCount`,`BlackPawnCount`) 
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=58796 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As can be seen, there is a composite index on the Count fields (the fields I search on).

I am using the query below:

EXPLAIN

```
SELECT * FROM endgames WHERE WhiteQueenCount >=0 AND WhiteRookCount >=3 AND WhiteBishopCount >=0 AND WhiteKnightCount >=0 AND WhitePawnCount >=0 AND BlackQueenCount >=0 AND BlackRookCount >=0 AND BlackBishopCount >=0 AND BlackKnightCount >=0 AND BlackPawnCount >=0
```

UNION

```
SELECT * FROM endgames WHERE WhiteQueenCount >=0 AND WhiteRookCount >=0 AND WhiteBishopCount >=0 AND WhiteKnightCount >=0 AND WhitePawnCount >=0 AND BlackQueenCount >=0 AND BlackRookCount >=3 AND BlackBishopCount >=0 AND BlackKnightCount >=0 AND BlackPawnCount >=0
```

The output of that explain is the following:

1, 'PRIMARY', 'endgames', 'range', 'IX_PieceCounts', 'IX_PieceCounts', '10', '', 8421, 'Using where' 
2, 'UNION', 'endgames', 'ALL', 'IX_PieceCounts', '', '', '', 58795, 'Using where' 
, 'UNION RESULT', '', 'ALL', '', '', '', '', , ''

This may take up to 3 seconds in the live environment on a table with 60,000 rows. Is there any way I can optimise the query? In particular I am noticing that the IX_PieceCounts index is not being used in the second part after the UNION and I see "using where" and a large number of rows having to be examined.

Thanks in advance, 
Tim

Comment: The easiest thing I can spot is to take the star out of both select clauses and get only what you need, you should see some improvement there.

Answer (score 0):

The overlap for the data might not be big enough to warrant use of the index the second time, Im guessing in most of your games, both players will move a rook more than 3 times, so you got most (but not all) of the results in your first union query.

If your query is not parameterized, or doesn't have other things depending on it, you could try taking that union out. 
Also choose the fields that you want to query out, rather than a star, that will take some time off. Itll have to be the same select for both.

```
SELECT 
   games.ID,
   IF(blackRookCount3.ID IS NULL,0,1) AS blackRookIsGreaterThan3,
   IF(whiteRookCount3.ID IS NULL,0,1) AS whiteRookIsGreaterThan3
FROM endgames 

INNER JOIN 
   endgames games
ON endgames.ID = games.ID      
AND WhiteQueenCount >=0
AND WhiteBishopCount >=0 
AND WhiteKnightCount >=0 
AND WhitePawnCount >=0 
AND BlackQueenCount >=0 
AND BlackBishopCount >=0 
AND BlackKnightCount >=0 
AND BlackPawnCount >=0

LEFT JOIN 
   endgames blackRookCount3
ON endgames.ID = blackRookCount3.ID      
AND blackRookCount3.BlackRookCount >=3 

LEFT JOIN
   endgames whiteRookCount3
ON  endgames.ID = whiteRookCount3.ID      
AND whiteRookCount3.WhiteRookCount >=3 

INNER JOIN
   endgames whiteAndBlackRooks
ON games.ID = whiteAndBlackRooks.ID      
AND whiteRookCount3.ID IS NOT NULL 
AND blackRookCount3.ID IS NOT NULL
```